# Как при помощи OpenPyXL вывести все ячейки столбца?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

Я новичок в Python и мне нужен совет, как вывести из файла Excel все ячейки нужного столбца, например, все значения столбца 'B'. 
Я пытался использовать модуль OpenPyXL для решения этой задачи.

```
from openpyxl import *

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['List1']

list_B2 = sheet_ranges['B2'].value
print(list_B2)
```

Получаю только одну указанную ячейку. 
Как решить мою задачу при помощи этого модуля? Возможно, есть другие модули для работы с .xlsx ?

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте циклом вытащить:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['List1']
column_b = sheet_ranges['B']

for i in range(len(column_b)): 
    print(column_b[i].value)

# Или просто как итератор перебрать столбец:
for cell in column_b:
    print(cell.value)
```